# BarChart with relative abundances as chart labels

Tags: charts

I want to make the following bar chart, but with relative abundances on top of the chart labels. I get the absolute numbers, but not the relative abundances:

```
data = {{43, 14}, {193, 158}, {37, 18}, {12, 3}, {5, 1}, {4, 0}};

BarChart[data
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Above] &)
 ]
```

I get it to work if I have only one bar per category, but not with two bars per category, because I don't know how to make the division inside the LabelingFunction separate for each category:

```
data = {43, 193, 37, 12, 5, 4};

BarChart[data
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[N[#/Total@data], Above] &)
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labeleddata = Transpose@Map[Labeled[#, Rotate[#2, Pi/2], Above] & @@ # &, 
                  Transpose /@ ({#, N@Normalize[#, Total]} & /@ Transpose@data), {2}]; 

BarChart[labeleddata]
```

[image]

or

```
labeleddata2 = Transpose[Labeled[#, Rotate[#2, Pi/2], Above] & @@@ # & /@ 
                          (Transpose /@ ({#, N@Normalize[#, Total]} & /@ Transpose@data))];

BarChart[labeleddata2]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I am sort of glad there isn't a simple answer.